# best way to fix inspection for soapclients in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm v3 and have some code which connects to a certain SOAP service. (via a simple PHP SoapClient) No problems whatsoever. But the PHPStorm inspector cant find the methods available of the WSDL and thus cant recognize the used methods:

```
$this->soap = new SoapClient('somewsdl url');
$issues = $this->soap->getIssuesFromJqlSearch($this->auth,
    'ticketId = '.$ticket->getId().'
    AND impId ~ "'.$currentImplementation->getIdentifier().'"', 1);
```

Everything works but the method 'getIssuesFromJqlSearch' which is provided by the external WSDL is highlighted with the mentioning of an undefined method... How can i 'tell' PHPStorm what should/could be used (or explain how to parse the WSDL?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not perfect, since it does not parse the WSDL and you have to do it manually, but works fine after the initial setup.

Create a class extending the native `SoapClient` and use annotations to add virtual methods:

```
/**
 * @method mixed getIssuesFromJqlSearch
 **/
class VendorSpecific extends \SoapClient {}
```

Or you could generate such client yourself, implementing all the methods as a proxy to `self::__soapCall()`. See my [SoapClient generator](https://github.com/mlebkowski/wsdl-generator) for reference. The upside is that it can parse the WSDL, though not perfectly.

Comment: Thanks that would see to work. Just creating a manual stub indeed 'fools' the autocomplete and such. Too bad PHPStorm cant read the WSDL and generate the stub from there.. I've voted a feature request to allow for this feature (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3616)

Comment: You can generate PHP classes from WSDL with projects like this: http://wsdl2phpgenerator.github.io/wsdl2phpgenerator/ - works fine for me. It's under active development.

Answer (score 2):

You can **suppress** the inspection for this statement from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, `right arrow` menu:

[image: suppress]

Comment: But thats not what i want... I would like to see it the other way around: define a WSDL that's understood by PS and thus autocorrects the typ0's